# SQL query all register but select only one of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that I have one table looking like this:

| ID | ClientID | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JX100 | John | Canada |
| 2 | JX100 | John | Japan |
| 3 | JX690 | Rob | EUA |
| 4 | PX301 | Alice | France |

And My query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID,Name,Country FROM CLIENTS
```

OUTPUT:

| ClientID | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JX100 | John | Canada |
| JX100 | John | Japan |
| JX690 | Rob | EUA |
| PX301 | Alice | France |

I want to take that:

DESIRED:

| ClientID | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JX100 | John | Canada |
| JX690 | Rob | EUA |
| PX301 | Alice | France |

TL;DR

I just want to select one country for all Clients, I don't want to get repeated rows.

Comment: There are not repeated rows in your output though. John is registered(?) to 2 countries

Comment: Do you care which one?

Comment: Just care about the top one of the countries. The row is not entire repeated @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number()over() with common table expression like below:

```
with cte as (
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID,Name,Country,row_number()over(partition by  ClientID   ,Name    order by Country) rownumber FROM CLIENTS)
select * from cte where rownumber=1
```

**Row_number()over(partition by  ClientID   ,Name    order by Country)** will generate a sequence for contries starting from 1 against each clientid and name. So when you will select rownumber=1 this query will select one country for a single clientid,name combination.